# Copy NTFS MetaData: Good Idea or Bad?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, metadata, robocopy

I wanted to "migrate" or "mostly clone" a drive to a new one.  So, I robocopied a drive, and discovered that the destination has a few missing MetaData files including files from:

```
B:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$Txf

 B:\$Extend\$RmMetadata

 B:\$Extend\$UsnJrnl

 $Secure:$SDS
```

I know some of the missing data is also located in streams (ADS).  e.g.  `$UsnJrnl:$J`, or `$UsnJrnl:$Max`.  Also to note is that I am copying from a drive that is not the active one to one that is also not the active one.  I am working out the details of how to perform the copy.  I can probably use WinHex or Ubuntu to make it happen.  Is there anything I should be worried about in copying these missing files?  I don't know if the $UsnJrnl would be of any benefit on the new drive; the $RmMetaData seems to be regarding removable media - doesn't sound necessary or negatively impactual if missing on the new drive.  I don't really understand what $Secure:$SDS is about... other than it is called the Security Descriptor Stream.  No idea what it holds.  In total, it's about 100MB that is missing and it concerns me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to migrate one hard drive to another, especially if there are operating system or executable files on it, you will have a very difficult time doing that robustly with file-copy tools like robocopy.

You will need specialized disk cloning software, possibly running off bootable external media, to accomplish this task.

There is a plethora of such software for this task, both open-source and proprietary. I don't have enough experience with these to recommend any in particular but I'm sure you can find your own reviews and such.

Comment: Only major hurdle is the file system metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/en/) for years which is easier to use than a cloning software and more robust than RoboCopy.

It copy files with their *Alternate Data Streams* from a NTFS filesystem to another NTFS filesystem. You just need to tick the *AltStream* checkbox.

[FastCopy main window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egte3.png)

It can also replicate the Creation Date and Access Control List, which is very useful when you really want to copy all meta data.